# Printing a tuple

Tags: python

I have a tuple `m = ('ring', 5)` and I want to print it out as `ring 5`.

I have tried `print %s %f, %m` and I get an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: print "%s"%repr(m) should do fine whatever it contains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> m = ('ring', 5)
```

what you were trying to do

```
>>> print "%s %f" % m
ring 5.000000
```

Except `%f` means `float` and you want `%d` for `int`:

```
>>> print "%s %d" % m
ring 5
```

Comment: Probably the error was the lack of quotes, more than %f versus %d

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yeah that was the error, I just fixed it in the first solution without explaining

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo - yes it was the quotes!!  It's always something silly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `format` it is more elegant

`print '{0} {1}'.format(*m)`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5082482/243431

Answer (score 0):

```
m = ('ring', 5)
print m[0], m[1]
```

prints

```
ring 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> m = ('ring', 5)
>>> for element in m:
        print element,
ring 5
```

This might work.